# Build .APK after editing with dex2jar and jd-gui?

Tags: java, android, compilation, apk

I have used dex2jar with the help of [THIS](http://androidorigin.blogspot.com/2011/02/dex-format-to-jar-format.html) tutorial to extract .class files, and used jd-gui to view the classes. but I cant edit in jd-gui so, through jd-gui, I "Saved All Resources", now I have a .zip with .java classes so I edited them with a Notepad++.
So now I have a .zip with all the classes in .java and I edited what I wanted, how do I build back everything to a .apk to install to the phone? Is this the wrong way to edit a .apk?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Omar. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the decompiler does not decompile all correctly (in fact with obfuscation you'll never get a code without errors) you can't recompile the code...

If you edit the classes into eclipse, you'll see that there are a bunch of errors and a bunch of $NameClassNumber and other stuff.

Maybe you can edit than repackage some resources, but the code not (luckily).

Comment: It depends on the result of decompilation.. If you can retrieve a functional code or you are skilled in fixing it you can edit it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953532/is-it-even-possible-to-modify-apk-by-adding-additional-class-to-dex-and-re-pac

Comment: Omar you can edit the smali files then repackage in a functional apk, but it's not java.

Answer (score 4):

I have never had good results of dex2jar.

I extract the dex file from the jar with 7-zip, then use baksmali http://code.google.com/p/smali/ to decompile the dex file to ".smali" files (not as easy to understand as class files but it's manageable), and then use smali (included with baksmali) to recompile.  Use 7-zip again to put the new classes.dex file back in the jar and done.